# Looping through Array - Print only once?

Tags: arrays, loops, ejs

Working on looping through a set of data and adding the names of foods to one array. Current set up below:

Note: The allDBfoods is a collection of food data seeded in the database.

```
<% var breakfastFoods = []  %>
<% for (var food of allDBFoods) { %>
    <% if (food.breakfast == true ){ %>

        <% breakfastFoods.push(food.name) %>
        <% console.log(breakfastFoods)%>
    <% } %>
<% } %>
```

This works but returns

```
[ 'Eggs' ]
[ 'Eggs', 'Bacon' ]
[ 'Eggs', 'Bacon', 'poptarts' ]
```

I only want it to make one array. Any advice?

Comment: A bit of code indentation would have guided you to understanding the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use `log` outside of `for` loop:

```
<% var breakfastFoods = []  %>
<% for (var food of allDBFoods) { %>
    <% if (food.breakfast == true ){ %>    
        <% breakfastFoods.push(food.name) %>
    <% } %>
<% } %>
<% console.log(breakfastFoods)%>
```

Comment: Well. Not sure why I didn't get that to work haha. Thanks!